# How to create 2 dropdownlist boxes and 2 textboxes with date format dynamically by clicking on a button AND Saving & retrieving the data in database

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
        <title>Untitled Page</title>     
        <script type="text/javascript">     
         function GetDynamicTextBox(value)      
         {   
             return '<input type="CheckBox"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<input name="DynamicTextBox1"
             type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<input type="button"
             value="Remove" onclick=" RemoveTextBox(this)" />'     
         }

         function AddTextBox() 
         {
             var div = document.createElement('DIV');
             div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
             document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
         }

         function RemoveTextBox(div) 
         {
             document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
         }

         function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() 
         {
             var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
             if (values != null) 
             {
                 var html = "";
                 for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) 
                 {
                     html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
                 }
                 document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
             }
         }
         window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">    
            <div id="TextBoxContainer">
                <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
            </div>
            <br />
            <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Text" onclick="AddTextBox()" />
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnPost" runat="server" Text="submit" OnClick="Post" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;    
using System.Collections;    
using System.Configuration;    
using System.Data;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Web;    
using System.Web.Security;    
using System.Web.UI;    
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;    
using System.Xml.Linq;    
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace Row_By_Button
{    
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string Values;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Post(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] textboxValues1 = Request.Form.GetValues("DynamicTextBox1");            
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            this.Values = serializer.Serialize(textboxValues1);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add cotrols do this : tweak this for adding more controls as per your req

```
function addTextBox()
{
    var inpt = document.getElementById('input_template');//parent Div name
    element.setAttribute("id", "TextBox1");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("value", "");
    element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
    inpt.appendChild(element);
}
```

To retrieve and insert to db

```
string s = Request.Form["TextBox1"].ToString(); //C#
```